# XBMCbuntu: Unofficial Ubuntu Derivative, or just a version of Ubuntu with extra software?

Tags: discussion, scope

> Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289267/dns-not-working-in-xbmcbuntu

So, the above linked quesiton has prompted a question: is XBMCbuntu a release of Ubuntu, with a few prepackaged softwares just added while still using the entirety of the Ubuntu repos (unmodified), or is it an unofficial derivative?

The answer to this question would determine whether the XMBCbuntu question is marked as offtopic or not.

Comment: @jrg so the question is therefore offtopic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the latter (A unofficial derivative) or the former (a release, with some prepackaged software while still using the default repo), it's off-topic.

But if it was a plain-vanilla-official-derivative Ubuntu install, and then they installed XBMC on it, then that's ok.

So, ask before voting.

Comment: shouldn't it matter if it is even relevant? For many things it's all the same, even then it would be offtopic? For instance some question about the usage of apt?

Comment: @Nanne the same argument is made for Mint by people.  Mint's not a supported derivative by any of the other Ubuntu support mediums, and that also applies here.